# How to get response of last redirect in WKWebview

Tags: ios, swift, google-chrome, token, wkwebview

I'm trying to get access_token of an app from Facebook. When user login Facebook, It returns access_token. I can get it on chrome in below section (Screenshot). However, I can't get that response on WkWebview. I think It is because, chrome shows last response of url (redirected one) but WkWebview shows first one.

[image: Chrome]

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
    print(navigationResponse.response)
    let headers = (navigationResponse.response as! HTTPURLResponse).allHeaderFields
    let req = URLRequest(url: navigationResponse.response.url!)
    decisionHandler(.allow)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i truly understand your question.

`func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse` is used for deciding if a navigation should happen after the response is known.

Try monitor `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!)` or `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!)` if you want to obtain the full callback Url from facebook with the token.

Comment: I did it via monitoring navigationaction instead of navigationresponse. I'll share my answer, later. Thank you :)

Comment: Hello @MrSomeDev. I will so much like to know how you were able to get this donne.